# Encoding files with utf-8 using Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

I can't set ruby to use the utf-8 for encoding files.

Script like this

```
# encoding: UTF-8
puts "ą"
```

works fine

but such

```
# encoding: UTF-8
File.open("test.txt", "w:UTF-8") do |f|
  f.write "ą"
end
```

causes the console pops up

```
task.rb: 4: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
```

despite the fact that all commands turning on utf-8 encoding are applied.

I'm using ruby 2.0.0-p451 from rubyinstaller for windows.

Comment: Is your source file utf-8 encoded? I recall that the default windows file encoding will break utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

Ok everything works fine, I just changed enconding in notepad++ from ansi to utf-8.